# What I have to do to update my current app with a new app fro scratch?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, updates, androidx

I have an app that I created using `Flutter`. I published it on Play Store (Android) and App Store (iOS). Everything is working fine. However, I just can't update it to the brand new `AndroidX` library. Everything falls apart.

So I decided to create a new app from scratch, using Flutter, with these new libraries.

**My question is**: I will be able to update my current app (Play Store and App Store) with this new app if I use the same name, same AppID and same PackageName on it?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: No, I did not. I decided to create a new one today and this question came on mind.

Comment: If you have the same package name and keystore to sign the apk, then it should be fine.